# how to use dataflowtemplate in spring cloud data flow API.1.7.3

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

My questions is how to use dataflowtemplate in the spring cloud data flow api.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/api/

`register(String name, ApplicationType type, String uri, String metadataUri, boolean force)`

I know what is uri, but I don't know what is metadataUri, can you give a example?

when I launch a task, it always said that null point mistake? What does it mean?

`dataFlowTemplate.taskOperations().launch("task",null,null);`

```
DataFlowTemplate dataFlowTemplate = new DataFlowTemplate(new URI("http://localhost:9393/"),
    restTemplate);

dataFlowTemplate.appRegistryOperations().register("batch", ApplicationType.task,"maven://com.example:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",null,true);
dataFlowTemplate.taskOperations().create("task","batch");
dataFlowTemplate.taskOperations().launch("task",null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

congrats on the 1st StackOverflow post!

There are a few samples in the reference guide re: [`DataFlowTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dataflow-template). The --metadataUri` property is options, it is used to register a companion artifact that includes the key/value options of all the supported properties for the registered applications. Again, more details in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-metadata-artifact).

We also have a whole suite of a test harness that relies on `DataFlowTemplate` to create and launch Tasks in SCDF. Please refer to [`AbstractTaskTests`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-acceptance-tests/blob/91ad602619297b08bba9e69f57d7726f936d8e9f/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/acceptance/test/AbstractTaskTests.java) to learn more about the usage patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: DataFlowTemplate dataFlowTemplate = new DataFlowTemplate(
            new URI("http://localhost:9393/"),restTemplate);

    dataFlowTemplate.appRegistryOperations().register("batch", ApplicationType.task,"maven://com.example:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",null,true);
    dataFlowTemplate.taskOperations().create("task_job","batch"); In this code, I successfully register and create a task named  task_job. I can find task_job and run it by type command line: task launch task_job in the data flow shell. It launch succefuly.

Comment: But if I don't use shell, I use restful call (dataFlowTemplate.taskOperations().launch("task_job",null,null);) to launch the task_job. It said that Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: Again, please have a look at the example I shared above. It does exactly what you're trying to do with RESTTemplate. No shell is used.